# Sonar test is failing with -org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_035b120.asm.MethodTooLargeException: Method too large: ****$.<init> ()V

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_035b120.asm.MethodTooLargeException: Method too large: ****. ()V

I want to exclude that class or test case on sonar test run

```
<sonar.test.exclusions>src/test/**.java</sonar.test.exclusions>
```

Tried but not working.

Please provide me the way to pass this sonar test.